# Can I reinstall Windows 10 if my disk space isn't clear?

Tags: windows-10, window, reinstall, reset

So I wanted to fully reset my pc, but it's stuck at 1%. A problem a lot of people have. And I'm wondering, if I can reinstall windows 10 withouth resetting my pc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an in place upgrade.

use Media Creation Tool to download windows 10 on to a USB.

Copy the files back to the desktop in a folder.

Run the setup program.

You can also boot from the USB stick and re-install windows losing everything.  You can even have it totally format your hard drive.

Obviously you would want to backup anything important before doing this.